# Tricky question involving finding a relation between the time derivative of an operator and a commutator of two operators

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, differential-operators

In order to get to the parts I am stuck at, I will add the examiners' solutions to each subquestion, which is needed to get to the subquestion that I am querying.

The following is a bizarre question from a highly ranked university quantum mechanics exam:

> Consider the quantity
>
> $$\hat{\mathcal{O}}_{mn}(t)=\int {u_m}^{*}(x,t)\hat{\mathcal{O}}\,u_n(x,t)dx$$
> for some operator $\hat{\mathcal{O}}$ which has no explicit
> time-dependence, where $u_n(x,t)$ and $u_m(x,t)$ are eigenstates of
> $\hat{H}$ at time $t$.
>
> Write this expression in terms of the eigenstates $u_m(x)$ and $u_n(x)$ at time $t=0$

[image: b)]

---

In the second line I believe that there is a mistake and $\int {u_m}^{*}(x,t)\hat{\mathcal{O}}\,u_n(x,t)dx$ should be $\int {u_m}^{*}(x,0)\hat{\mathcal{O}}\,u_n(x,0)dx$ since all the time dependence is in the exponentials out front.

Could someone please confirm or deny whether this is indeed correct?

---

> What is the time-derivative? $$\frac{d}{dt}\hat{\mathcal{O}}_{mn}(t)?$$

[image: c)]

---

> Consider the operator $\hat{\mathcal{O}} = [\hat{A},\hat{H}]$ and find $\hat{\mathcal{O}}_{mn}(t)$ for this case. Find a relationship between $\frac{d \hat{A}_{mn}}{dt}$ and $\hat{\mathcal{O}}_{mn}(t)$.

[image: d)]

---

In the first integral there may be a typo as I think that $$\int {u_m}^{*}(x)[\hat{A},\hat{H}]u_n(x,t)dx$$ should be $$\int {u_m}^{*}(x)[\hat{A},\hat{H}]u_n(x)dx$$

I think that $$\hat{\mathcal{O}}_{mn}(0)=(E_n-E_m)\langle{\hat{A}\rangle}$$ when the examiner writes "Comparing to the above" in the last line, I presume the part that is being compared is $$\frac{d}{dt}\hat{\mathcal{O}}_{mn}(t)=-\frac{i}{\hbar}\left(E_n-E_m \right)\hat{\mathcal{O}}_{mn}(t)$$

I can't figure out how to derive the relationship
$$\frac{d}{dt}\hat{A}_{mn}(t)=-\frac{i}{\hbar}[\hat{A},\hat{H}]_{mn}\tag{1}$$
as I don't even think it is correct since the question asked to find $\color{red}{\hat{\mathcal{O}}_{mn}(t)}\,\color{red}{\text{for this case.}}$

It also asked for $\color{red}{\text{a relationship between}}\,$ $\color{red}{\frac{d \hat{A}_{mn}}{dt}}$ $\color{red}{\text{and}}\,$ $\color{red}{\hat{\mathcal{O}}_{mn}(t)}$ not $[\hat{A},\hat{H}]$.

---

I would really like to understand how to derive relation $(1)$, so if anyone could give me any hints or advice on how to go about this it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you are right about all the typos, but I think the answer is essentially correct

$$ \hat{\mathcal{O}}_{mn}(0)= [\hat A, \hat H]_{mn}(0)=(E_n-E_m){\hat A}_{nm} (0)$$
so $$ \hat{\mathcal{O}}_{mn}(t)= [\hat A, \hat H]_{mn}(t)= e^{-\frac i \hbar   (E_n-E_m)t     }(E_n-E_m) {\hat A}_{nm} (0)
\\ = (E_n-E_m) {\hat A}_{nm} (t)
$$
Also, assuming $ \hat A$ has no explicit time dependence, it must satisfy
$$  \frac{d}{dt}\hat{A}_{mn}(t)=-\frac{i}{\hbar}    (E_n-E_m) \hat A_{mn}(t)
\\ = -\frac{i}{\hbar}  \hat{\mathcal{O}}_{mn}(t)
$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer (+1). The part I can't understand is how you deduced that $\hat{\mathcal{O}}_{mn}(0)= [\hat A, \hat H]_{mn}(0)$ and $\hat{\mathcal{O}}_{mn}(t)= [\hat A, \hat H]_{mn}(t)$ when all we are given from the question is that $\hat{\mathcal{O}} = [\hat{A},\hat{H}]$. I would appreciate it if you could expand a little on this in your answer. Many thanks so far.